# Left navigation Redirecting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I have Backup and Restore the site collections from PROD to TEST Fram Using DB attach Process. Backup restore has successfully Completed but Left Navigation in Test environment is  redirecting to Prod "URL" in all Site Collections. Do we have any Scripts or Do we need to change in  Webpage in QuickLanch or Do I need to Change all 107 Site collections  Manually going to SiteAction -->Navigation -->Edit.?

Please Help me out, if you have any idea about this issue.

Comment: Consider using relative URL's instead of absolute URL's.  You'll avoid this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:
 1. Use PowerShell and this [arcticle](http://sharepointryan.com/2013/04/15/fix-sharepoint-quick-launch-links-using-powershell/). Preffered.
 2. Edit url's in content DB. Not preffered.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: Yup,Alex I had other Question Can you help me out !! Migration from WSS3.0 to SharePoint 2010 Standard farm do you have any Idea or step to step to fallow !!!

Comment: Your farm have custom solution?

Comment: No Everything is OUT OF BOX!!!

Comment: Look for these thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5aa67a68-e175-4c55-a243-e6b7d6d46849/migrating-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010